# Website scraping using jquery and ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, screen-scraping

I want to be able to manipulate the html of a given url. Something like html scraping. I know this can be done using curl or some scraping library.But i would like to know if it is possible to use jquery to make a get request to the url using ajax and retrieve the html of the url, and run jquery code on the html returned ?

Thank You

Comment: Whose HTML do you want to modify? Do you have write rights to that URL?

Comment: Note that it is also possible (now) to do something similar with nodejs + jsdom.

Answer (score 8):

I would like to point out that there are situations where it is perfectly acceptable to use jQuery to scrape screens across domains.  Windows Sidebar gadgets run in a 'Local Machine Zone' that allows cross domain scripting.

And jQuery does have the ability to apply selectors to retreived html content.  You just need to add the selector to a load() method's url parameter after a space.

The example gadget code below checks this page every hour and reports the total number of page views.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        body { 
            height: 120px;
            width: 130px;
            background-color: white;
        };
    </style>
</head>

<body>
Question Viewed:
<div id="data"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var url = "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1936495/website-scraping-using-jquery-and-ajax"

    updateGadget();

    inervalID = setInterval("updateGadget();", 60 * 1000);

    function updateGadget(){

        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#data").load(url + " .label-value:contains('times')");
        });

    }

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I ran this verbatim and it doesn't seem to work?  Firebug merely shows the GET in red...which I take it means "denied".

Comment: I don't think that'll get around the cross-domain policies that exist with ajax - you would only be able to deploy this code within the stackoverflow site.

Comment: Same Origin Policy is not an issue on Safari and a properly initialized Chrome

Answer (score 4):

You cannot do Ajax request to another domain-name than the one your website is on, because of the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) ; which means you will not be quite able to do what you want... At least directly.

A solution would be to :

- have some kind of "proxy" on your own server,
- send your Ajax request to that proxy,
- which, in turn, will fetch the page on the other domain name ; and return it to your JS code as response to the Ajax request.

This can be done in a couple of lines with almost any language *(like PHP, using curl, for instance)*... Or you might be able to use some functionnality of your webserver *(see [`mod_proxy`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html) and [`mod_proxy_http`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy_http.html), for instance, for Apache)*

Comment: Same Origin Policy is not an issue on Safari and a properly initialized Chrome.

Answer (score 3):

Its not that difficult.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  baseUrl = "http://www.somedomain.com/";
  $.ajax({
    url: baseUrl,
    type: "get",
    dataType: "",
    success: function(data) {
      //do something with data
    }
  });
});
```

I think this can give you a good clue - http://jsfiddle.net/skelly/m4QCt/

Comment: Your JsFiddle doesn't work: `Refused to execute script from 'https://raw.github.com/padolsey/jQuery-Plugins/master/cross-domain-ajax/jquery.xdomainajax.js' because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
(index):1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.mashable.com/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://fiddle.jshell.net' is therefore not allowed access`

Answer (score 1):

http://www.nathanm.com/ajax-bypassing-xmlhttprequest-cross-domain-restriction/

> The only problem is that due to security in both Internet Explorer and in FireFox, the XMLHTTPRequest object is not allowed to make cross-domain, cross-protocol, or cross-port requests.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of curl, you could use a tool like [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) which will automate loading the page in the browser. You can run JavaScript with it.

Answer (score 0):

I do this with a small PHP proxy, temporarily stripping IMG tags to speed up load times. I've wrapped it in a jQuery plugin that makes it relatively easy to use, see [here](http://brianzeligson.com/jqueryScrape/) for demo/github link