# Downloading a lot of slippery data

Tags: html, web-scraping

I have access to a web interface for a large amount of data. This data is usually accessed by people who only want a handful of items. The company that I work for wants me to download the whole set. Unfortunately, the interface only allows you to see fifty elements (of tens of thousands) at a time, and segregates the data into different folders.

Unfortunately, all of the data has the same url, which dynamically updates itself through ajax calls to an aspx interface. Writing a simple curl script to grab the data is difficult due to this and due to the authentication required.

How can I write a script that navigates around a page, triggers ajax requests, waits for the page to update, and then scrapes the data? Has this problem been solved before? Can anyone point me towards a toolkit?

Any language is fine, I have a good working knowledge of most web and scripting languages.

Thanks!

Comment: If you need the data for legitimate reasons, can't you contact the vendor and ask for a web service call to do all of it at once?

Comment: Yeah - we tried that about six months ago, and are still in contact with the company trying to convince them to give us a database dump. They're under the impression that since we can access all the data they have no reason to give us a dump, despite the fact that we paid for at and can only access 50 elements at a time. So my boss told me to automate it, but I don't know how.

Comment: could you not sniff out what the ajax calls are and then replicate the calls directly?

Comment: How difficult is the authentication (HTTPS? just a cookie based login)? What does one of the AJAX calls look like? Personally, I would dissect the structure of the AJAX calls and request them using Python. It can't be harder than this: "How can I write a script that navigates around a page, triggers ajax requests, waits for the page to update, and then scrapes the data?"

Comment: HTTPS, yes. I know how to do some scraping in Python, but I'm having trouble authenticating. Is there a way to authenticate a web scraper on an HTTPS sight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually just use a program like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) or [Live HTTP Headers](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/live-http-headers/) and just watch what's happening behind the scenes. 99.9% of the time you'll see that there's a querystring or REST call with a very simple pattern that you can emulate.

Answer (score 1):

### If you need to directly control a browser

Have you thought of using tools like [WatiN](http://watin.sourceforge.net/) which are actually used for UI testing purposes but I suppose you could use it to programmaticly make requests anywhere and act upon responses.

### If you just need to get the data

But since you can do whatever you please you can just make usual web requests from a desktop application and parse results. You could customize it to your own needs. And simulate AJax requests at will by setting certain request headers.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this ?

[Website scraping using jquery and ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1936495/website-scraping-using-jquery-and-ajax/4308559#4308559)

http://www.kelvinluck.com/2009/02/data-scraping-with-yql-and-jquery/