# I'm getting empty response while ajax with Jquery to external URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape other sites for Meta data given a URL. But I'm having a problem. I have an empty response from the ajax request, I can see it goes in the error function, but there is no explicit error. Any ideas? this is the code:

```
function scrapeURL(url){
    console.log("scraping");
    $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "GET",
            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                  console.log(xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
                  console.log(status);
                  console.log(error);
            },
            success: function( data ) {

                console.log("done");
                console.log(data);
                $( "#msgid" ).html( data );
            }
    });};
```

Now, in firebug i can see a GET to the url and a 200 response, but I can't see the HTML response and the output of the error function is:

```
xhr.status = 0
xhr.statusText = error
status = error
error = (empty)
```

Any ideas? what am I missing here?

Comment: You're missing the obvious error that is in your error console. It says something similar to "Access Denied due to Same Origin Policy" Search that error and you will see why you can't do this client-side. I don't typically test in Firefox first, so i'm not sure exactly where in the firefox javascript console this kind of error would appear.

Comment: You are having a same-origin issue, have you tried researching it yet?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1936495/website-scraping-using-jquery-and-ajax might be useful

Comment: I suspected that Same Origin Policy was the issue, but I couldn't find it in the firefox console.. I'll search if sending the ajax to my server and scrape FROM there would work. I guess that is my only choice? which alternatives you suggest?